# Как бы вы объяснили "Бродил ли он"

Tags: словоупотребление

Как бы вы объяснили

> Бродил ли он...

?

Comment: А в чём заключается вопрос, собственно? Бродить - это ходить без цели, гулять, блуждать.

Comment: What extra meaning does ли он gives to brodil (if at all)?

Comment: @H0wardR0ark Though comments are good feature, but remember that you can always edit your own question to make it more clear.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE! When asking for phrase or word meanings, please always provide some context (where did you see the phrase). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's rather difficult to explain this phrase without any context.

One meaning of verb *бродить* is *walk around, wonder aimlessly, roam*. Particle *ли* indicates uncertainty.  And pronoun *он* means *he*. Therefore the full phrase can mean *has he really been roaming aimlessly...*

There's a completely different possibility though.  Another meaning of verb *бродить* is *ferment*.  When, for example, you pour alcohol over fresh berries and leave the mixture to ferment, in Russian, word *бродить* describes this process.  Therefore, taking into account meaning of particle *ли* and pronoun *он*, the phrase can mean *has it realy been fermenting...*

Note that *бродить* is an imperfect verb, indicating an action in the process, not necessarily completed - and this affects the translation.

In either case, this structure is commonly indicative of a question, where the person asking is not sure whether it happened or not:

> Бродил ли он?
>   Has he really been roaming aimlessly?
>   Has it really been fermenting?

It can also be used without being a question, usually indicating pondering on the subject and uncertainty of events:

> Бродил ли он - неизвестно.
>   Whether he really was roaming aimlessly is not known.
>   Whether it really was fermenting is not known.

Answer (score 3):

"Ли" has many meanings. In your example it's used as an interrogative particle in a direct question without negation (вопросительная частица в прямом вопросе без отрицания). More examples:

> ◆ Далеко ли тут до беды? (И. С. Тургенев)
>
> ◆ Занятий мало ль есть у ней: // Грибы солить, кормить гусей, // Заказывать обед и ужин, // В анбар и в погреб заглянуть, — // Хозяйки глаз повсюду нужен: // Он вмиг заметит что-нибудь. (А. С. Пушкин, «Граф Нулин», 1825 г.)

Complete list of meanings and other examples can be found at the [wiktionary page](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8).

"Бродил ли он?" has the same meaning as "Он бродил?" ("Did he wander?")

Note that if there are more words in the sentence, meaning can change. For example, it could be a conditional disjunctive conjunction (условно-разделительный союз):

> "Бродил ли он или стоял на месте, — ничего не менялось."

That can be explained as "Nothing was changed regardless of the fact that he was wandering or standing" (may be not entirely correct translation).